# c++ template syntax error

Tags: c++, syntax, templates

My C++ is a little rusty having worked in Java and C# for the last half dozen years. I've got a stupid little error that I just cannot figure out.

I've pared the code down as much as possible.

```
#include <list>
template<class T> class Subscriber
{
    virtual void published( T t ) = 0;
};

template <class T> class PubSub
{
private:
    std::list< Subscriber<T>* > subscribers;
public:
    void publish( T t );
};

template<class T> void PubSub<T>::publish( T t ) 
{
    for( std::list< Subscriber<T>* >::iterator i = subscribers.begin(); i != subscribers.end(); ++i )
        i->published( t );
}
```

When I try and compile this (by including this header file in a code file), I get the following error:

```
../util/pubsub.h: In member function ‘void PubSub<T>::publish(T)’:
../util/pubsub.h:18: error: expected `;' before ‘i’
../util/pubsub.h:18: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for( typename std::list< Subscriber<T>* >::iterator i = ...
     ^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 6):

```
for( typename std::list< Subscriber<T>* >::iterator i = subscribers.begin(); i != subscribers.end(); ++i )
```

You need the `typename` because `iterator` is a dependent name. The compiler has to check the template type `T` before it knows whether `iterator` is a type or a value. In those cases, it assumes it to be a value, unless you add `typename`.

Answer (score 4):

This

```
std::list< Subscriber<T>* >::iterator
```

needs to be this

```
typename std::list< Subscriber<T>* >::iterator
```

The compiler assumes nested names in templates are static variables (not types) until told otherwise.